# joomla sidebar comments module/plugin/component

Tags: joomla-2.5, module, plugin

I would like to find component/module/plugin (does not matter) for showing comments in sidebar. For example - Phoca guestbook component + phoca guestbook latest entries module component is good solution for me, but phoca guestbook latest entries module not free. I would like to find free solution. The main goal - make conversation with users in sidebar, for fast consulting (like FAQ for users). Last comments or somethik like that would be nice too.
sorry for english

Comment: What you are looking for is a chat application, imho

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want instant questions and answers, then it's better to use a chat module just as **Nagarjun** mentioned.

If you want to show only the latest articles in a spesific category, then you will need an article slider.

You can find free versions of Joomla modules, componenets and plug-ins in [**extensions.joomla.org**](http://extensions.joomla.org) web site. Just write "**chat**" or "**article slider**" in the search bar and be sure to check "**Free**" in the releated field. It will list all free versions of modules, components and plug-ins.

Hope this helps.

Regards

Oguz